# Role of mathematics in science

Tags: soft-question

I want to know that what is the main role of mathematics in science. I mean to say is the main objective in any mathematical research should be finding some tool which may be of good use in other sister disciplines like Physics or Chemistry or something else. In perticular, if I mention pure mathematics, what is the main aim to develop new theories there? Do all of them have direct applications or we develop this with the hope that in future they may be used. Please through some light in this regard.

Comment: Some of us do it because it is beautiful, regardless of the potential applications.

Comment: Considering how cheap it is, this MAA pub [The Role of Mathematics in Science](http://www.maa.org/publications/ebooks/the-role-of-mathematics-in-science) looks like an appropriate book reference to your question.

Comment: I have (am currently watching) an absolute gem for you. In fact this reminded me of you. You absolutely have to watch this by a winner of the Fields medal: [T. Gowers 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsIJN4YMZZo), [T. Gowers 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NyqiEMilyns), .... You will see the rest. There are at least 8 parts (I am still watching). The title being "The Importance of Mathematics" at the millennium meeting in Paris.

Comment: @ J.W. Perry: Thanks for the information!